# How to view videos in Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, video, video.js

I need help on how to play my uploaded videos in my Laravel project. I can upload them and they show in the database but I can't play them in my view and I get this error 'The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported'. I'm using Video.js. Here is my code

Controller:

```
public function store(MovieRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $movie = new Movie;

        $movie->movie_name = $request->input('movie_name');

        if ($request->hasFile('uploaded_path')) {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('uploaded_path')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('uploaded_path')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $path = $request->file('uploaded_path')->storeAs('public/movies/', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'novideo.mp4';
        }
        $movie->uploaded_path = $fileNameToStore;

        $movie->save();

        $movie->actors()->attach($request->input('actor_id'));
        $movie->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
    }
    Session::flash('success', 'A movie was successfully UPLOADED in the database!');
    return redirect()->route('movies.index');
}
```

MovieRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'movie_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'uploaded_path' => 'mimetypes:video/avi,video/mpeg,video/mp4|required',
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:mysql.categories,id',
        'actor_id' => 'required|exists:mysql.actors,id'
    ];
}
```

View:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($movies as $movie)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $movie->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $movie->movie_name }}</td>


            <td>
                <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="200" height="100" data-setup="{}">
                   <source src="public/movies/{{$movie->uploaded_path}}" type='video/mp4'>
                </video>
            </td>


            <td>
            @foreach ($movie->actors as $actor)
                <a href="{{ route('actors.edit', $actor->id) }}">{{$actor->actor_name}} @unless($loop->last)
            , 
            @endunless</a>
            @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
            @foreach ($movie->categories as $category)
                <a href="{{ route('categories.edit', $category->id) }}">{{$category->category_name}} @unless($loop->last)
                        , 
                        @endunless</a>
            @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($movie->created_at)) }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('movies.edit', $movie->id) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

Comment: `src="public/movies/{{$movie->id}}"`  Are you really storing the filename as an integer?

Comment: I made a mistake, forgot to fix it and edit it. it is $movie->uploaded_path, but I still get the same mistake.

Comment: If you want to serve your movie using a public path, it needs to be relative to the public folder what is the path stored in `uploaded_path` ?

Comment: I agree with @adam, check the path to the video. Tried the same with the simple `video` tag and it works just fine.

Comment: @adam $path = $request->file('uploaded_path')->storeAs('public/movies/', $fileNameToStore);   this?

Comment: Whats the exact value in your table?

Comment: under uploaded_path column I have one value video_1542379322.mp4

Comment: @Gacho try `/public/movies/{{$movie->uploaded_path}}` or `/movies/{{$movie->uploaded_path}}`

Comment: @adam Tried both, still getting the error.

Comment: @Gacho try hitting the url directly in your browser.

Comment: @adam I apparently created a symbolic link for the storage directory using the artisan command php artisan storage:link and now my uploaded files are sent to storage/app/public/movies . What is the path that I should put in my view now?

Comment: @Gacho If I understand the documentation correctly it looks like that command would make items publicly available in your browser at `/storage` so try `/storage/movies/{{$movie->uploaded_path}}`

Comment: @adam It works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Create an endpoint to serve your movie:

```
Route::get('/movie/{id}', ['uses' => 'MovieController@downloadMovie']);
```

Add a method in your controller:

```
public function downloadMovie($id)
{
    $movie = Movie::findOrFail($id);
    // download the movie
    return Response::download($movie->uploaded_path);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
 <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="200" height="100" data-setup="{}">
     <source src="/movie/{{$movie->getKey()}}" type='video/mp4'>
 </video>
```